# How to compile boost unit test module with clang++?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, boost, g++, clang++

I'm trying to compile a boost unit test module with cmake and clang but ran into a linker error. I was able to produce the following minimal test case:

```
$ cat boost_test_test.cc
#define BOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE scanio
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(foo) { BOOST_CHECK(1); }
```

This compiles fine with `g++`:

```
$ g++ boost_test_test.cc -lboost_unit_test_framework
$ echo $?
0
```

But it does not with `clang++`:

```
$ /usr/bin/clang++-3.7 boost_test_test.cc -lboost_unit_test_framework
/tmp/boost_test_test-7e4892.o: In function `boost::unit_test::make_test_case(boost::unit_test::callback0<boost::unit_test::ut_detail::unused> const&, boost::unit_test::basic_cstring<char const>)':
boost_test_test.cc:(.text._ZN5boost9unit_test14make_test_caseERKNS0_9callback0INS0_9ut_detail6unusedEEENS0_13basic_cstringIKcEE[_ZN5boost9unit_test14make_test_caseERKNS0_9callback0INS0_9ut_detail6unusedEEENS0_13basic_cstringIKcEE]+0x58): undefined reference to `boost::unit_test::ut_detail::normalize_test_case_name(boost::unit_test::basic_cstring<char const>)'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

So during the linker stage I get an `undefined reference` error and this problem persists no matter the order of arguments to `clang++`.

Since it works fine with `g++` I suppose there is something `clang++` specific going on here?

This is with g++ 5.2.1, clang++ 3.7 and boost 1.58 on Debian Sid.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this on my computer, which boost version are you using?

Comment: @m.s. thanks, then there is hope. I added the versions to my initial question.

Comment: It also compiles fine at my machine, though I don't have access to both compilers' versions you are mentioning.

Comment: I have the same problem, gcc version 5.2.1 20150903 (Debian 5.2.1-16); Debian clang version 3.5.2-1 (tags/RELEASE_352/final) (based on LLVM 3.5.2); libboost-test1.58-dev 1.58.0+dfsg-3

Answer (score 3):

In Ubuntu Willy, Boost 1.58 Unit Test library is compiled with GCC 5.0. The library file `libboost_unit_test_framework.a` contains the mangled function `_ZN5boost9unit_test9ut_detail24normalize_test_case_nameB5cxx11ENS0_13basic_cstringIKcEE` that resolves to `boost::unit_test::ut_detail::normalize_test_case_name[abi:cxx11](boost::unit_test::basic_cstring<char const>)`

However, CLang does not seem to use the new ABI, so it searches for `_ZN5boost9unit_test9ut_detail24normalize_test_case_nameENS0_13basic_cstringIKcEE`, which is `boost::unit_test::ut_detail::normalize_test_case_name(boost::unit_test::basic_cstring<char const>)`.

In order to overcome this, define your own function in the test file:

```
namespace boost { namespace unit_test { namespace ut_detail {
    std::string normalize_test_case_name(const_string name) {
        return ( name[0] == '&' ? std::string(name.begin()+1, name.size()-1) : std::string(name.begin(), name.size() ));
    }
}}}
```

This should resolve the issue. If compiled with the same version of the compiler as Boost, it should be no problem, as the linker will simply ignore the library version of the  function.

Comment: more details about this problem with clang can be found here https://bugs.debian.org/797917 and here https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=23529

Comment: It is 2020 and this problem persists. This solution works but it doesn't scale well if one has many test files.